# Could not find gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-assets

I migrated from rail 4 to rails 5 but these gems are not working. Can anyone tell me how to solve it? When I do bundle install and check which gems are installed it says it has such gems. I'm using:

- ruby 2.5
- bundler: 2.3.25
- rails 5.2

```
gemfile: source 'http://insecure.rails-assets.org' do   
  gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap', '~> 3.3.6'   
  gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap-select', '~> 1.6.3'   
  gem 'rails-assets-angular', '~> 1.6.1'   
  gem 'rails-assets-angular-simple-logger', '~> 0.1.7'   
  gem 'rails-assets-ui-leaflet', '~> 2.0.0'   
  gem 'rails-assets-underscore', '~> 1.8.3'   
  gem 'rails-assets-highcharts', '~> 6.1.2'   
  gem 'rails-assets-highcharts-ng', '~> 1.2.1'   
  gem 'rails-assets-leaflet-draw', '~> 1.0.2'   
  gem 'rails-assets-esri-leaflet', '~> 1.0.5'   
  gem 'rails-assets-jquery.easing', '~> 1.3.1' 
end
```

error:

```
block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap (\~\> 3.3.6)' in locally installed gems. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

I removed them from the gemfile and it stops giving this error, but as I am migrating an application I need them

Comment: What happens if you run `bundle install`?

Comment: Thank you for your attention!
It installs the gems but when starting the application it gives the error message.
block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap (~> 3.3.6)' in locally installed gems. (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Comment: Does `bundle exec rails ...` at the start resolve the issue?

Comment: Thank you for your attention!
No resolve, same error

Comment: What if you drop the version restriction? `gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap'` instead of `gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap', '~> 3.3.6'`

Comment: rails-assets.org docs indicates you're supposed to use `source 'https://rails-assets.org'`. that may help.

Comment: Do you have a repo that you could share with us?

Comment: did you try `bundle update`. check if it updates gems. else as @anothermh said, try dropping specific version from gemfile. and I am also not sure about the source you are using for gemfile.